# BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2405: in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am new to laravel and facing an issue,I am calling a controller via ajax call ,it is calling controller but when controller is calling model it is giving 
"BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2405:" error.Following is my code

AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo url('master/add-car-to-db');?>", 
        method : "post",

        data :  completeData ,
        success : function (data){
                    data=parse.JSON(data);
            if(data.success == 1){
                            window.location="<?php echo url('master/add-car-view');?>";

                        }
        },
        error:  function(data,status){
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });
```

Controller:

```
public function postAddCarToDb(Request $request){
        $result = Master::addNewCar($request);
        echo $result;
        die;
         if ($result > 0) {
            echo json_encode(Array('success' => 1));
        } else {
            echo json_encode(Array('success' => 0));
        }
    }
```

Model:

```
public static function addNewCar(Request $request){
return "success"
}
```

Route:

```
Route::controller('master', 'MasterController');
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: rename: <?php echo url('master/AddCarToDb');?> and the method aswell public function AddCarToDb(Request $request){
        $result = Master::addNewCar($request);
        echo $result;
        die;
         if ($result > 0) {
            echo json_encode(Array('success' => 1));
        } else {
            echo json_encode(Array('success' => 0));
        }
    }

Comment: that wont work...Controller method not found it is showing

Comment: Can you post the entire error message?

Comment: url(/'master/add-car-to-db') add a slash before master

Comment: BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2405:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::addNewCar()
in Builder.php line 2405
at Builder->__call('addNewCar', array(object(Request)))
at Builder->addNewCar(object(Request))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(Builder), 'addNewCar'), array(object(Request))) in Builder.php line 1426
at Builder->__call('addNewCar', array(object(Request)))
at Builder->addNewCar(object(Request))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(Builder), 'addNewCar'),

Comment: @Leo_Kelmendi that is not working as well

Comment: @Jerodev there are many such error lines

Answer (score 0):

Reverse routing is deprecated in laravel 5 so on.

```
Route::controller('master', 'MasterController');
```

use

```
Route::post('master/add-car-to-db','MasterController@postAddCarToDb');
```

then in Controller

if you still want to use reverse routing you can

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo   action(YourController@yourAction) ;?>",  
    method : "post",

    data :  completeData ,
    success : function (data){
                data=parse.JSON(data);
        if(data.success == 1){
                        window.location="<?php echo url('master/add-car-view');?>";

                    }
    },
    error:  function(data,status){
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
```

Comment: still it is not working.Moreover i have muktiple functions in same controller calling same model, all are working fine except this one

Comment: i did accordingly ,it is  saying "COntroller Method not found".I think problem is in controller not in ajax call

Comment: @PranilPagare are you sure have you seen in debug tools?

Comment: yeah i am trying to solve  from quite some time .Either there is some config issue or something else @ Adnan Mumtaz

Comment: try `dd($result)` lets see what it says

Comment: [object Object] this is what i am getting in ajax error part

Comment: try to expand object

Comment: thing is this is alerted from controller.As iam using ajax noneis refted in controller ,hence i am alerting it in error and success part